# Some images not loading in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, blogs

When i upload images in my Word Press post, Images are not correctly appearing in my WordPress blog post. 
my blog address is
https://kufarooq21.wordpress.com

Can you please check and help me
Thanks and Regards,

Umer

Comment: Your site is loaded over HTTPS and its not allowing images to load over HTTP for security reasons. Are you using any CDN plugin on your blog? Try disabling them and test.

Comment: See what your image link says  : https://bitly.com/a/warning?hash=2nqhoCd&url=https%3A%2F%2F4.bp.blogspot.com%2F-UKNYW_WRKAg%2FWMpLEgClizI%2FAAAAAAACUrw%2FgjcRz4LrMnYrs_J8nfrLMHn-oHiuSbe2QCLcB%2Fs400%2F48055036.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images is being blocked by bit.ly as they seem potentially problematic.

Example:
https://bitly.com/a/warning?hash=2na7uDS&url=https%3A%2F%2F4.bp.blogspot.com%2F--D1CrUCl2Mk%2FWM41QJOMUKI%2FAAAAAAACUyI%2FdKutsuGgjtkrZ6CxYGg82lh5wRzoeKEMQCLcB%2Fs400%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You use an external link for the post like : `<img src="http://ift.tt/2nqhoCd" width="400" height="272" border="0">`

You need to download the image and upload to the media. And then you need to use this as an internal link of of your site. Like: `<img src="https://kufarooq21.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/stone.jpg" width="400" height="272" border="0">`

I hope This will help you.